# Placing an image on detected faces using opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv

Basically, I am working on my FYP which has one module of virtual clothes mirror.
The main task i want to about is:

1. Find the detected body part (Which has been done)
2. Next I want to place an image (clothes template) instead of square box

Basically the main thing is that i am new to c++ that's why having lots of hurdles.

Comment: You want to do it with respect to your camera pose!?

Answer (score 0):

what you want is augmented reality there are many tutorials on the Internet
http://www.instructables.com/id/Creating-your-Augmented-RealityAR/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jU6PcBS1pWw

Comment: I have surfed alot i have also done the face detection and using overlay function in opencv i have placed a picture in it but it is not  giving me a clear view please help urgent

Comment: It's *not* a definite answer to OP.